# Why is the code throwing "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"?

Tags: python, attributeerror, nonetype

I tried to run my code however it is throwing "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'" and I can't seem to install regex. I read that it is built-in but I dont know what to do. here is the code that throws the error:

```
while i>0:
    print("Number "+str(i))
    src = str(br.parsed())
    start1 ="¿"
    end1 = "?<"
    result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start1,end1), src).group(1) 
    print(str(result))
    question_index=questions.index(result)
    print("The answer is " + answers[question_index])
    question_form = br.get_form()
    question_form["user_answer"]=answers[question_index]
    br.submit_form(question_form)
    i=i-1
```

this line throws the error:

```
result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start1,end1), src).group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "install" the regex module `re`. You are correct that it is built-in, you do have it, and it is working fine. If you didn't have it, you would have gotten an `ImportError` when you tried to import it.

The problem is that your regex search is not finding any matches, so it is returning `None`. Then you're immediately trying to access the attribute "group" in `None` on the same line, which doesn't exist. Separate out the search from `.group(1)`, check the return type for `None`, and proceed only if the return is not `None`. If the return value of `re.search()` is `None`, then do whatever you want to handle the error - exit, display error message, [HCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire), whatever.

Change this:

```
result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start1,end1), src).group(1)
```

To something like this:

```
result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start1,end1), src)
if result is None:
    print("Error! No matches")
    return # or break, exit, throw exception, whatever

result = result.group(1) # reassign just the group you want to "result"
# carry on with the rest of your loop
```